# How can I download an audio when it completes buffering (Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, download

When I listen to an audio file on the internet using Chrome browser, I believe that it's automatically downloaded and stored somewhere on my hard drive because when I rewind it, it doesn't take a long time to be downloaded again. So if I listened to an audio file, where can I find it? I would not like to download it twice. I'd like to listen to the whole file (To download it somewhere on my hard drive) then, I'd like to find where it is downloaded. 
I'm talking about this of kind files (Kindly, Look at the link below).

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all

It's the audio file of HTML5 I think.

Comment: search for media download in chrome web store, you'll find lots of extensions that do this.

Comment: You can find the chrome cache internally, unsurprisingly at chrome://cache. Getting the file into a readable format though, takes a bit more work.

Comment: This might not be possible because of DRM.